# Why doesn't SymPy like to redefine a variable?

Tags: python, numpy, simpy

I have this session on [SymPy Live](https://live.sympy.org/):

```
Python console for SymPy 1.4 (Python 2.7.12)

These commands were executed:
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
>>> k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)
>>> f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function)

Warning: this shell runs with SymPy 1.4 and so examples pulled from
other documentation may provide unexpected results.
Documentation can be found at http://docs.sympy.org/1.4.

>>> import numpy as np
>>> V = np.array([[1, y, x, 1], [y, 1, z, 1], [x, z, 1, 1]])
>>> V = np.array([[1, y, x, 1], [y, 1, z, 1], [x, z, 1, 1]])
Exception in SymPy Live of type 
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
for reference the last 5 stack trace entries are
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/57.417397408462217066/shell.py", line 781, in post
    live.evaluate(statement, session, printer, stream)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/57.417397408462217066/shell.py", line 453, in evaluate
    if name not in old_globals or val != old_globals[name]:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The second assignment to `V` is identical to the first, but this second time SymPy throws an exception.

Did I do something wrong, and if yes, which part of the documentation did I miss?

Comment: It's not a good idea to mix `sympy` and `numpy`.  Some cases works, but you really have to understand how they interact to do it reliably.  The error is deep in sympy's evaluation, so it will be hard to trace.  We get errors like this when using boolean arrays in a `if` context, which expects a scalar boolean.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error in a `isympy` session.  `V` is an object dtype numpy array.  I have no problem rerunning that line.  Other than the fact that `x,y,z` are `sympy` objects, this is just a numpy array construction.  There's no `sympy` evaluation that I see.

Comment: @hpaulj - Ah, I also can't reproduce on the local workstation with Python 2.7.13 and SymPy 1.0 - what are your versions?